# If a tag badge is awarded in a "higher" level, it stops being rare in the "lowest" levels

Tags: support, achievements-dialog, rarest-badges

Maybe the title is a bit weird, so let me explain it:

In [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=profile) it used to appear the Silver badge for the [grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grep) ([9 people](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3487/grep) with it so far) as the rarest.

However, since I got its [Gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5255/grep) it is not showing any more. Instead, I see [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) ([awarded 19 times](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1437/awk)), [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) ([44 times](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/867/shell)) and [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) ([88 times](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/184/bash)).

Is this intentional?

I would understand that a tag badge appearing in all the columns may look a bit monotonous, but at the same time it loses the goal of showing what is the rarest you have achieved.

Another example:

- [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) was is the only to have the Silver badge for [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1101/css-selectors) but it is not shown in his profile since the Gold badge is already displayed.

---

As a side note, I also think that the way these badges are chosen to be shown could also take into consideration how common is to get other generic badges. For example, I have the Illuminator badge (awarded [35 times](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) so far) and is not shown as Rarest. In my opinion, this is rarest because more people are eligible to receive it instead of the very specific tag badges in which not many people provide answers.

Comment: Why do you need to see the silver badge? If you have the gold, you clearly had to have received the bronze and silver first to get it, so it's unnecessarily repetitious. Why waste the space and clutter the screen for things that are simply meaningless to display?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ken White basically nailed it in his comment.  It sounds like it's acting as intended:

**Each column (gold, silver, bronze) displays the rarest three of that type, unless there's already a badge displayed (in another column) that makes it clear you have that type.**

If users could only see one type at a time (silver, say), you'd be right that it's weird not to show your rarest silver just because you have the gold.  But since we're showing all three types, it's pretty redundant.  If you've earned a gold tag badge, you *must* have earned the silver and bronze, so using two more slots to display something already conveyed conveys no additional achievement, but prevents us from showing off some others.

Comment: Thanks for the official confirmation : )